# find coordinates of masks produced by segment anything by meta

Tags: segment

[text](https://colab.research.google.com/github/roboflow-ai/notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/how-to-segment-anything-with-sam.ipynb?ref=blog.roboflow.com#scrollTo=CS_WhY60XMNL)

the above link is to segment a image. It gives a perfect output of segmented image and also masks.
but how do i find the coordinates of the all produced  masks.

when the code is giving the list of masks i need their coordinates as well. how can i get that.

the below code shows how the masks are produced.

```
sv.plot_images_grid(
images=masks,
grid_size=(15, int(len(masks) / 15) + 1),
size=(26, 26))
```

Answer (score 0):

The information regarding the mask is returned as a 'dict', the coordinates of the bounding box can be obtained by using the 'point_coords' keyword

```
for lm in sam_result :
  print (lm.get('point_coords')
```